# Android Studio doesn't push app to phone

Tags: android, build, android-studio, apk

When I press 'run' in Android Studio, my app builds successfully. The debug APK is generated in build/outputs/apk but the APK is not pushed to my phone. It's rather annoying because I now have to actually email the APK to myself and install it from email on my phone in order to test my app. Has anyone had a similar problem, or does anybody know how I could possibly fix this? I googled my hat off but I didn't find anything that could help.

Notes:

I'm using the latest Android Studio on the latest OSX.
I also have the latest build tools and the latest Gradle version.

Comment: It's not meant to push the **testing apk** on the phone, unless you use your phone instead of the emulator (via **USB Debugging**).

Comment: Open Run/Debug Configuration  and select radio with show chooser dialog in Target Device section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your build config

and make sure you select "deploy default APK"

[image: go to you build config]

[image]

Comment: Such a simple problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I upgraded from Android Studio 1.5 to 2.1 this started happening a **lot**.

If you already have your build config set correctly, just *restart Android Studio*.

The more complex Android Studio gets, the buggier it becomes.  I have to restart it at least twice a day for various reasons, and here is yet another.  Sigh.